# change state if min-width 900px

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found a good jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/thurstanh/emtAm/2/

```
  <article>

     <details>
      <summary>Step by Step Guides</summary>

        <summary>Getting Started</summary>
        <p>1. Signup for a free trial</p>
      </details>
  </article>
```

and If I add  it will expand. Now I want it to be expanded when I am on a screen that is above 900px, but when I am on a screen below 900 pix how do I change that to not be expand. I know that if I remove the "open" in  it will be collapsed. Is this where jquery comes in hand or how do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried using matchmedia js? https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all the jQuery you need:

```
$details = $("details"), $window = $(window);
$window.on('resize',function(){
    if($window.height() > 900) $details.attr('open',true);
    else $details.filter('[open]').removeAttr('open');
}).resize();
```

It will automatically add or remove the [`open` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#Attributes), depending on the height of the window when it is resized.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0tdbbfmd/

Note: I used `600` in the demo rather than `900` so the effect is demonstrated within the preview size.

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery's `preventDefault()` and `$(window).resize()`

check this [DEMO (resize)](http://jsfiddle.net/emtAm/555/)  (resize the viewport)

```
$(document).on('click', 'details', function(e) {
if($(window).width() < 900) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
});

$(window).resize(function() {
if($(window).width() < 900) {
    $('details').removeAttr('open');
}
});
```

Comment: This also works fine and thank you so much for the fast respons

Answer (score 0):

You should know that the details and summary elements aren't supported in Firefox and IE, so you might want to look elsewhere for this type of functionality. Otherwise Mooseman has the right idea, You'll want to bind on the resize and toggle the open attribute. Here's a little more reading:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=details

http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/

---

Comment: I will be looking in to this since I will be using this alot. Thank you so much for the help